# What is the maximum number of characters in the utm_content param in GA?

Tags: google-analytics

We want to differentiate people who followed our daily product email blast in Google Analytics. I could use the product ID for utm_content, but it would be easier to read if I use the SEO friendly URL path, such as: `http://www.oursite.com/products/really-great-new-product`

```
https://www.oursite.com/?
 utm_source=a&utm_medium=b&
 utm_term=c&
 utm_content=Can-I-use-a-really-long-content-tag-like-this-one-or-is-this-going-to-break-something&
 utm_campaign=d
```

Answer (score 3):

If `utm_content` is a URI, then the according to `RFC 2616` they can be any length (however URIs over 255 bytes in length may cause issues for older browsers and proxies). In reality, most browsers can't process URIs over 2000 characters in length.

See this answer for more details on the subject of URI length:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/557748